# Overloaded method value json with alternatives: (jsonRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]) using Spark in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, implicit

I am trying to convert a JSON String *jsonStr* into a Spark Dataframe in Scala. Using InteliJ for this purpose.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkExample").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
import spark.implicits._
var df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS)
df.show()
```

Getting the following error while compilation/ building the project using **Maven**.

> Error:(243, 29) overloaded method value json with alternatives:
>   (jsonRDD:
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame 
>   (jsonRDD:
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>    (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  (path:
>   String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String])
>   var df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS)

*Note*: I was not getting the error while building with SBT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below method was introduced in Spark 2.2.0

```
def json(jsonDataset: Dataset[String]): DataFrame =
```

Please correct your version of Spark in maven's pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonStr))
var json_df = spark.read.json(rdd)
var df = json_df.toDS
```

(or combine it in one variable, up to you)
.

You're trying to pass `Dataset` into `spark.read.json` function, hence the error.